# Dos Goto command skip

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, goto

I wrote this program to convert fractions to percent but my goto commands are being skipped. It goes through the program and skips the if statements. Here is the code:

```
@echo off

:menu
Echo Fraction to Percent=1
Echo Percent to Fraction =2
set /p choice =Enter the number of your choice:
if choice == 1 goto ftp
if choice == 2 goto ptf
if choice == 3 Exit

:ptf
pause

:ftp
set /p tn= Enter the top number:
set /p bn= Enter the Bottom number:
set /a mtn= %tn% * 100
set /a cf= %mtn% / %bn%
set /a cf2= %cf% * 10000
set /a mtn3= %tn% * 1000000
set /a cf3= %mtn3% / %bn%
set /a cf4= %cf3% - %cf2%
set /a cf5= %cf2% / 10000
echo %cf5%.%cf4%
goto continue


:continue
set /p con =Continue? (y/n):
if con ==y goto ftp 
if con ==n goto menu
```

Answer (score 1):

### **The problem**

on this line: `set /p choice =Enter the number of your choice:`
`choice` is a var so therefore it should be reference as a var like so
`%choice%` instead of `choice` so as an if i suggest doing...
`if "%choice%"=="1" goto ftp`

### Tips

---

Try adding quotes like On the [wikipedia (batch file)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Advanced_Windows_batch_example_.28using_CMD.EXE.29_-_conditional_shutdown) page Example
`if "%choice%"=="1" goto shutdown`
Also see more info on if-statements here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/if.php